# ASP.NET MVC3 Model Binder with radio button list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

Hi
I have a model like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Header {get;set;}
  public IList<ChildModel> Children {get;set;}
}

public class ChildModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool IsDefault {get;set;
}
```

In the Create action of the controller I would like to have this:

```
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
  //...save...
}
```

It works for the Header property and for the Name properties of the child collection (I use Html arrays: Children[x].Name ), but the model binder doesn't set the value of the IsDefault property that is used with a RadioButton list.

Is there a way to get the strongly typed model correctly set using the radio buttons with the bool children? I don't want to implement a custom model binder for this...if possible.

thx

Comment: Could we see the html of the rendered radio buttons?

Comment: I used this: 
<input id="IsDefault" name="IsDefault" type="radio" value="1" />

Comment: Just as a comment, because I'm not sure, I think the name/id of the Checkbox must be Childldren.IsDefault in Order to get Mapping work.

Comment: That's what I thought, that's why I wanted to see the html

Comment: I already tried those names: name="Children.IsDefault" and name="Children[x].IsDefault" where x is the index. Don't work :-(

Comment: Mhm... for both name and id I assume?